# How to show an additional single point on a line graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a data set which shows the "efficient frontier" curve and a data point showing the decision made. I wish to have the data point be plotted in relation to the frontier but as an isolated point (the frontier is a curve/connected lines). I'm stumped as far as accomplishing this is concerned.

Here is a picture of the data set. I wish to have the point "My Choice" show up as a single point on the graph in relation to the frontier curve. Any way I can get the "My choice" point to be below the curve in the appropriate order?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your x-axis is not uniform, you should convert your chart to a scatter plot type (e.g., straight lines, no markers) from line graph.

Plot the single point as a separate series. You can then update the data for the single point and it will appear as a single point on the graph.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Pictures would be helpful...